# How to restore deleted mockie api URL

Tags: javascript, postman-mock-api-server

I am using mockie API (https://designer.mocky.io/) since 3 years and today when I try to run the project I got to know that mockie URL is no longer (which I was using). Is there any ways to restore it ?

I can make a new API but I want that data which I donot have I was underimpression that this url never be deleted.

I tried to get the data from the archieve but haven't got that as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is off topic ;in this site we provide code help. Have you tried contacting their support?